# Python cropping a TIFF with shapefile shifts the output slightly to the East

Tags: python, clip, rasterio

I have a shapefile that I use to crop GeoTIFFs. However everytime I use my code to do that, it slightly shifts my entire cropped TIFF to the East and I have no idea why.
The pictures below show how well the original TIFF (uncropped) fits, and the second image shows how shifted the cropped TIFF is (I plotted only the boundaries of my shapefile, so it is more readable).
TIFFs and shapefile are all in EPSG:32607 (UTM 7N).

Link to a Google Drive containing: .shp file, .shx file, and the TIFF.

[Google_drive_link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nW9UQPk7NRYXIT1LM6M5V9hwd7yp3WKK)

Do you know why that is happening ?

[image: Original uncropped tif]
[image: Cropped/shifted tif]

The code that I use is:

```
def Clipper(raster, option):

  path = './glacier.shp'
  
  # Read Shapefile
  with fiona.open(path, "r") as shapefile:
      shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

  # read imagery file
  out_image, out_transform = rio.mask.mask(raster, shapes, crop=True, nodata = np.nan)

  # Check that after the clip, the image is not empty
  test = out_image[~np.isnan(out_image)]

  if test[test>0].shape[0] == 0:
    passaran = 0
  else:
    passaran = 1

  # convert the zeros into NaNs
  
  return(out_image, passaran)

# Read a dummy src
raster = rio.open('./S2_2018_09_08.tif')
out_meta = raster.meta

# Clip the raster
array_out, passaran = Clipper(raster)

# Save the clip as a tif
with rio.open('./clipped.tif', "w", **out_meta) as dest:
              dest.write(array_out)
```

Metadata raster: [image]
Metadata shapefile: [image]

Comment: Try using the array shape and `out_transform` as per the [docs example](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html#:~:text=crop%3DTrue%20in%20this%20example) instead of `raster = rio.open('/content/dummy.tif')`

Comment: It doesn't work, it actually shifts it even more. The only option that shifts it the least is what I do, without updating the metadata

Comment: I'm so sorry, I added a link to a Google Drive containing the files. Thank you for your time !!

Comment: Thank you for trying ! I wonder if it comes from my installation. I work with Google Colab so I have no idea if it somehow impacts things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code worked for me with minor modifications:

```
import rasterio as rio, fiona
import rasterio.mask as mask
import numpy as np

raster = 'S2_2018_09_08.tif'
clipped = 'clipped.tif'
path = 'glacier.shp'


def Clipper(raster, vector):


    # Read Shapefile
    with fiona.open(vector, "r") as shapefile:
        shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

    with rio.open(raster) as src:
        # read imagery file
        out_image, out_transform = mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True, nodata=np.nan)

        # Check that after the clip, the image is not empty
        test = out_image[~np.isnan(out_image)]

        if test[test > 0].shape[0] == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("Empty output")

        out_meta = src.profile
        out_meta.update({"height": out_image.shape[1],
                         "width": out_image.shape[2],
                         "transform": out_transform})

    return (out_image, out_meta)


# Clip the raster
array_out, out_meta = Clipper(raster, path)

# Save the clip as a tif
with rio.open(clipped, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(array_out)
```

[image]

[image]